# PHPUnit test only succeeds with a short sleep before the assertion

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-9

I have a few tests that behave pretty weird.

The test keeps failing, but when I put a breakpoint or a `sleep(1)` before the assertion it succeeds.

**An example:**

```
    public function test_it_confirms_time_pair()
    {
        $this->actingAs($this->authorizedUser);
        $this->assertNull($this->testTimeWork->confirmed_at);
        $this->post(route("times.confirm", $this->testTimeWork));
        // sleep(1); <-- Without this line or a breakpoint above, the tests fails.
        $this->assertNotNull($this->testTimeWork->fresh()->confirmed_at);
    }
```

The controller action in the background only sets one field in one specific row.

Any idea where this comes from?

Comment: As I understand, you're saying that the controller action for updating the confirmed_at happens in the background (which might not be ideal if you really need that confirmation to be visible in the system immediately)
if you really have to keep it in the background, try changing the phpunit configuration to ensure your `QUEUE_CONNECTION` is sync, also try to mock any calls to actual services with delays. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mocking